# Scrollbar in Tkinter not scrolling listbox or deleting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to use the following code, but i'm running into problems depending on who i choose to be the master of my scrollbar.

I don't know exactly what to try since i couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

```
fr = Frame(root)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
fr2 = Frame(root, height=34)
fr2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

text_area = Listbox(fr2, width = 28, height= 34)
text_area.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=20)

sb = Scrollbar(fr2)
sb.grid(column=1, row=0)

text_area.config(font = ("Courier New", 12), yscrollcommand = sb)
```

If i use `fr2` as the master of `sb`, my scrollbar appears very small and does not scroll `text_area` (Although my mouse wheel and up/down keys are able to.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAs7Y.jpg.

If i use `text_area` as it's master, however `text_area` is simply deleted https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOLxK.jpg.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two things to get a scrollbar to work:

1. you must configure the `command` option of the scrollbar to call the `set` method of the widget to be scrolled
2. you must configure the `yscrollcommand` option of the widget to update the scrollbar.

Also, there's nothing in the listbox, so the scrollbar won't work since there's nothing to scroll.

For the scrollbar to fill the space vertically, you need to use the `sticky` option if you're using `grid`. It also needs to span the same number of rows that the widget it is controlling, assuming you want them to be the same height.

Here's a working example based off of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

fr = Frame(root)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
fr2 = Frame(root, height=34)
fr2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

text_area = Listbox(fr2, width = 28, height= 34)
text_area.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=20)

sb = Scrollbar(fr2, command=text_area.yview)
sb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns", rowspan=20)

text_area.config(font = ("Courier New", 12), yscrollcommand = sb.set)

for i in range(100):
    text_area.insert("end", "item #{}".format(i))

root.mainloop()
```